# How to configure MODBUS on a Cyclades TS100?

Tags: networking, serial

I have a Cyclades TS100 which is used to communicate with a Modbus Slave. I selected **Protocol: Modbus** and configured **MODBUS Serial Mode: RTU**

The thing is, I event don't get a connection to the Serial Server on my selected port. What is the secret?

(The device itself works fine, even over the Serial Server, if I configure it to **Socket Raw** and speak to it via Modbus/RTU over TCP)

**UPDATE**: it seems that sometime in the past it was decided to comment out the modbus service from inetd.conf, so this was the sole reason the communication didn't work.